# JSON $ref to java object

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

I wish to initialize a java object like

```java
class Order {
   public Collection<Product> products;
   public Collection<Insurance> insurances;
}

class Product {
...
}

class Insurance {
   Product insuredProduct;
   ...
}
```

from a JSON string posted through the standard springboot - jackson mapping chain.

I wish to have a JSON where the product isn't duplicated: I would like an `Insurance` instance to have a reference to one of the `Product` instances present in the `products` collection.

How should the JSON be structured? I read the "pointer" specs but it doesn't seem to pin the problem.

Comment: `but it doesn't seem to pin the problem.` What problem?

Comment: there is no such construction with jackson, you may not be able to use $ref, but use a nested structure, which looks exactly like your class